# Why I can't boot debian 7 from usb stick?

Tags: installation, debian, usb-boot

I downloaded a [live ISO from the web](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/debian-live-7.0.0-i386-lxde-desktop.iso) and saved it as debian7.iso.

I then I flashed it onto my USB:

```
dd  if=/home/debian7.iso  of=/dev/sdb
```

I rebooted my computer, and set it to boot from "removable boot", but I cannot install from the USB stick.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Is the usb device formatted to fat?

Comment: yes i hvae formatted it to fat

Comment: can you at least boot from the stick? Do you see the debian installer menu?

Comment: how have u flashed? i mean manually? i suggest use http://www.isotousb.com/ ISO to USB, it worked always for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it by google.

```
menuentry 'Debian wheezy in usb ' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    insmod loopback
    loopback loop  (hd1,msdos1)/hybrid.iso
    linux   (loop)/install/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename=/hybrid.iso root=UUID=D0F8-2160
    initrd  (loop)/install/initrd.gz
}
```

Comment: Please flesh out your answer to make it more useful to readers. Where is the menuentry held?

Answer (score 0):

A "better" way to get a USB stick booting with a Linux disk may be to use "unetbootin", which actually builds the distro on the disk and installs a bootloader - which I believe you will find a more reliable way of booting it.

Answer (score 0):

@it_is_a_literature:

It helps to state the make & model of your system, not just so you can get an answer, but also so that others facing the same problem can be better informed.

I would **not** recommend Unetbootin. In my experience it does not work with Debian 7 or its derivatives.

`dd if=/... of=/... bs=4M; sync` is the best way to write the iso to usb pendrive.

Boot to usb by adjusting your boot device order in the BIOS menu (usually accessed by hitting 'F2' at power-on).

At GRUB menu:

```
Scroll down to 'Install'.

Press 'tab' key.

At bottom of screen, some text will appear.

At end of text:

Press 'space' key.

Enter (without quotes) 'vga=normal fb=false'.

Press 'enter' key.
```

The installer should now initialise.

This works for EeePC 701 series.